# Before insert trigger doesn't change column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this simple trigger, which should change the data before insert.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function product_fts_create_trg() returns TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        new.name := 'example';
        return new;
    end
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER "product_fts_create_trigger" BEFORE INSERT ON "productmodel" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE procedure product_fts_create_trg();
```

But it doesn't change column value. I thought, that this trigger doesn't processed, but if i change new.name to null (this column has a not null constraint), i got a error, which indicates, that trigger are works.

I use Tortoise ORM with sql query down below (i guess that this didn't ruin trigger, but mb it will be useful for discussion)

```
INSERT INTO "productmodel" ("id","created_at","modified_at","deleted","deleted_at","fts","name","short_description","long_description","price","old_price","currency","status","weight","length","width","height","count_available","address","text_verification","product_verified","delivery_types","delivery_payed_by","user_id","video_id","video_verification_id") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26): ['41ab62f0-1cab-47b5-a360-fcc9fbaf3b69', datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 1, 9, 39, 33, 360691, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 1, 9, 39, 33, 360713, tzinfo=<UTC>), False, None, None, 'Iphone 20', None, None, 100.0, 100.0, 'rub', 'review', None, None, None, None, 0, None, None, False, '["pickpoint"]', 'self-delivery', 3, None, None]
```

Very interesting that I have BEFORE UPDATE trigger and it works.

```
create function product_fts_trg() returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as
$$
    BEGIN
        if old.name <> new.name or old.short_description <> new.short_description or old.long_description <> new.long_description
            then new.fts := 'example';
        end if;
        RETURN new;
    end
$$;

alter function product_fts_trg() owner to vlad;
```

Comment: On its own, it should work... so check if there is another trigger that also sets the name or returns OLD.

Comment: Try `insert into productmodel` without Tortoise ORM using any database IDE like PgAdmin or DBeaver, your trigger function is correct syntax and should be work without problems. Maybe your ORM internally uses insert and update. Or @JGH is right.